# Make Shinyapp use new input across sessions

Tags: r, shiny

I´m using a shinyapp on an opensource shiny-server to display a dashboard on multiple devices. I want to give the opportunity to change the plots on all dashboards from a local PC.
If the input is altered in any session, all sessions should update their plots to this new input. How do i do this? Can i save the input in a global variable?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {


  observe({
    invalidateLater(10000)
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
     p<<- hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({print(p)})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate an `reactiveValue` in the global file and use this instead up the original input

In principal all objects initiated in the global file are shared over sessions.

**Example**

**UI **

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("It's Alive!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot", height=250)
  )
))
```

**Server **

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a histogram. The expression is
  # wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot
  observe({
    RV$bins = input$bins
  })
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = RV$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

})
```

** Global **

```
RV <- reactiveValues(bins = 10)
```

When a user changes the number of bins the **histogram** will changes for all users **but not the slider**.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sorry, i don´t get it. Are reactive elements possible in the global part?

Comment: @Niels yes it is possible please see my updated post

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. The only thing is, that when i open the dashboard in a new session, the global value gets overwritten. It would be perfect, if that wasn´t the case - if only the slider input would alter things. But i guess your solution is as good as it gets?